# How to set a fixed header within the Twenty Twelve WordPress theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Having started to create my own Wordpress Blog, I have got stuck on fixing my Header in place.

I have had only slight exposure to CSS/JavaScript so I am winging it as I learn along the way! Most of what I want to achieve has already been done, but I would just like to try and get this header fixed before I add my posts etc.

Upon searching this on the Interne I can only really find the below and added this into my style.css file;

```
#masthead {position:fixed; top:0px; margin:auto; z-index:100000; width:100%;}
```

this now fixes the Header Image and Navigation in place, but slightly off center, but the rest of my page falls behind this still now. One problem is that the actual background of the Image and Nav is opaque.. please see the screenshot below

```
Before code - http://tinypic.com/r/2vxm69t/6
After code - http://tinypic.com/r/34jd2t1/6
```

I believe I need to maybe create a separate 'div' within my header.php, or amend this in some way but tbh, I am not 100% sure on what actually would make this work as I have never done this before. Ideally, the line I added below the Nav links, shown on the screenshot before adding this code, this would indicate the bottom of the header and as you scroll, the rest would disappear under this. The background as a whole would remain white, and in center to the rest of the page, still including the gap at the top which revels the background.

!! I must apologise for the screenshots, it isn't very clear but I hope this shows what is happening and is clear enough, I will be hosting this asap!

Links to my 'style.css' & 'header.php' are as follows - if you need anything else please let me know;

```
style.css - http://codepad.org/c4BnqxlF
header.php - http://codepad.org/w4z19VLW
```

I hope somebody can help as I think this will look great on my blog, then I can get posting!

---

**EDIT**

Amended code, now showing correct alignment and background, but still showing a white section above the header image - best shown on the following screenshot `http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=126bd7c&s=6`

```
#masthead {background: #FFF;position:fixed; top:0px; height: 350px; z-index:100000; width:960px;} 
#main {margin-top:335px;}
```

.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Just need to put in a margin-top to it and move it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to adjust your code to fit properly but here is an example on how you can perform what I think you are trying to achieve.

In your code you need to define a background color and height of your image + nav.  After that you would want to create a margin for the id="main" to be below the the rest of your information which would be the margin-top of image + nav links.

**Update:** Added Margin-top to 24px

```
#masthead {background: #FFF;position: fixed; top: 0px; height: 350px; z-index: 100000; width: 100%;margin-top: 24px;} 
#main {margin-top:350px;}
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/6VcZe/1/

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was after, thought I would paste your reply in first and see what happened and after adding @Adrian suggestion to the below, this now show's much better!

#masthead {background: #FFF;position:fixed; top:0px; height: 350px; z-index:100000; width:960px;} 
#main {margin-top:335px;}

Background now showing white and alignment is correct. Text is being hidden upon scrolling and header is still fixed as expected

http://tinypic.com/r/126bd7c/6
http://tinypic.com/r/2m6n529/6

Comment: There is still an issue with the top of the header image though, I am not sure what this could be, testing my code at the moment though!! 'functions.php' states Width 960px, no Height stated but I know this to be 250px, I assume this is OK as this was left from the theme default and I have not amended this. Also the actual size of the image I uploaded to the header matches that. Just not sure why there is a white section still showing at the top, maybe I can excluded this from the 'div id=masthead' or play about with certain widths/heights ? will have look!

Comment: if you put a margin at the top of the masthead you can move it down a little.  Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Robert, I did add a 'margin-top:' as suggested and this did bring the header/nav links down to the correct position which is perfect! but upon scrolling down you can now see the website content scrolling above the header image in the gap between that and the top of the page :/

Comment: Removing the 'margin-top:' places the 'unknown' white box above the header image at the very top of the page, which tbh I don't actually mind. Only thing is, I would need to resize the white box to touch the very top/bottom of my page, or to set the whole background to white and not have the coloured sides at all.

Comment: Background set to all white and works brilliantly! I will host this tomorrow after I finish work so it can be previewed.. I'm happy with it (but will still look into resolving this properly, I am never satisfied with my designs so might need it in future) really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

To properly center align your header you need to define a width for your header div:

```
#masthead { width: 900px }
```

This will allow the auto margin technique to work properly, even without the position property.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian appreciate it :) adding your suggestion resolved the alignment issues!!

I have commented on the above answer with screenshots of what is showing now, there is still a white section showing above the header images, not sure why that is so just testing my code, thought I'd let you know :)